# Имя объектов потока

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

Добрый день.

У меня возникла сложная ситуация с возможностью определения имени конечного обекта потока, то есть откуда идет поток в (любом) процессе (стартовый адрес), я могу определить, а вот к чему этот поток обращается - файл, библиотека... (если не замыкаеться на себя), я не в состоянии найти. Как это можно реализовать при использовании C#/WMI/WinAPI?

P.S.
Заранее благодарен, можно хотя бы ссылочку?

Comment: Если это потоки исполнения, то только анализ кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел утилиту для решения проблемы но ни как не могу получить вывод

```
public async void ProcessHandle()
{
    Process InfoHandle = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    InfoHandle.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    //InfoHandle.StartInfo.Arguments = "Ping 192.168.1.1";
    InfoHandle.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    InfoHandle.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    InfoHandle.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    InfoHandle.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    InfoHandle.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
    InfoHandle.Start();
    await InfoHandle.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("handle -a -p " + RequestWMI_Process.AbbreName[Form1.BufIndex].ToString());
    Task <string> StringsHandle = InfoHandle.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
    InfoHandle.WaitForExit();
    InputFromPropertyProcess.textBox1.Text = await StringsHandle;
    //InputFromPropertyProcess.listBox6.Items.Add(StringsHandle[1]);
    //InputFromPropertyProcess.listBox6.Items.Add(StringsHandle[2]);
}
```

**В Win7 перехват вывода строки ещё как то работает а Win8.1 оно (Окно) зависает, без результата.**

Comment: А права есть?

Comment: На админа??? есть

Comment: Убрал await и ожидание, окно перестало зависать, но вот вывода нет, хотя в Win7 работало

Comment: Может ему flush не хватает?

Comment: Он зависает на этой строке 
Task <string> StringsHandle = InfoHandle.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
Попробовал зделать так 
string StringsHandle = InfoHandle.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
то же самое, то есть на сколько понимаю он не может завершить операцию чтения вывода.

Answer (score 0):

Это ваш код? Если да, применяйте логирование. Если нет, вам в помощь специальные инструментальные средства, наподобие [Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)'а.